# Set checkbox default value to checked in Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working with Access databases, and in one table I have field called "Active". This field has a checkbox and I need to set its default value to checked?

For example, I'm appending data to this table from Excel sheet that has 10000 rows and i can't go one by one and check them. So, what I want is when I append this sheet to the table that all checkboxes are checked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved, this worked for me. What I've done is that I set table properties like this:

[image]

and populated my cells on excel sheet with 1, and there it is.

If there is a better way, let me know.